# How to click a button from multiple buttons on same page in selenium web driver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, test-design, load-testing

Here my requirement is need to click on one button from multiple buttons, but which are having same class and type on same page. I need to click on button number 4 from below example.

For example

```
1. button type="button" class="button" onclick="checkout.setMethod();"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>

2. button type="submit" class="button" onclick="onepageLogin(this)"><span><span>Login</span></span></button>

3. button type="button" title="Continue" class="button" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button> 

4. <button type="button" class="button" title="Continue" onclick="shipping.save()"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>
```

**I have tried various methods**     **Please look at below mentioned which I have tried.**

i)
  `WebElement button = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button[@class='button' and @type = 'button' and @onclick = 'shippingMethod.save()']")).get(3);    button.click();`

ii)
`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@oneclick,'shippingMethod.save()']//button[contains(text(),'continue')]"))).click();`

iii)

```
String cssSelectorOfSameElements="button[class='button'][type='button']";
List<WebElement> a=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button[@class='button' and @type = 'button']"));

//  a.get(0).click();            
//  a.get(1).click();        
//  a.get(2).click();   


a.get(3).click();
```

Please suggest me, to overcome this issue. Looking forward to your suggestion. See my html code.

Continue

```
</div>
<div class="col-2">
<h3>Returning Customer</h3>
<form id="login-form" action="http://stage-retail.example.com/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post">
<fieldset>
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="qTQ1K2M3AHVALnNg" />
<ul class="form-list">
<li>
<label for="login-email" class="required"><em>*</em>E-mail</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" id="login-email" name="login[username]" value="" />
</div>
</li>
<li>
<label for="login-password" class="required"><em>*</em>Password</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="password" class="input-text required-entry" id="login-password" name="login[password]" />
</div>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="buttons-set">
<div class="clearfix">
<a href="http://example.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/" class="f-left">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="button" onclick="onepageLogin(this)"><span><span>Login</span></span></button>
</div>
<div class="other-login">
<h3 style="display: none;" class="mobile-title">Other Checkout Options</h3>
<div class="fb-connect-container">
<div class="aw-fb-login">
<a class="aw-fb-login-button" href="#" onclick="aw_fb_login(); return false;">Sign in with Facebook</a>
</div>
<div id="fb-loader" style="display:none;">
<p class="loader" id="loading_mask_loader">
<img src="http://www.example.com/preloader.gif" alt="Loading..." />

<span>Please wait...</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="amazon-login-default">
<strong>- OR -</strong>
<div class="button-holder" id="AmazonPayButtonBefore"></div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li id="opc-billing" class="section saved">
<div class="step-title">
<span class="number">2</span>
<h2>Billing Information</h2>
<a href="#">Edit</a>

</div>
<div id="checkout-step-billing" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
<form id="co-billing-form" action="">
<div class="fieldset">
<p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
<ul class="form-list">
<li id="billing-new-address-form" class="scaffold-form">
<div class="fieldset">
<input type="hidden" name="billing[address_id]" value="6427608" id="billing:address_id" />
<ul>
<li class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:email" class="required"><em>*</em>Email Address</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="d@test.com" title="Email Address" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="fields"><div class="customer-name">
<div class="field name-firstname">
<label for="billing:firstname" class="required"><em>*</em>First Name:</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" id="billing:firstname" name="billing[firstname]" value="f" title="First Name" maxlength="255" class="input-text required-entry" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="field name-lastname">
<label for="billing:lastname" class="required"><em>*</em>Last Name:</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" id="billing:lastname" name="billing[lastname]" value="k" title="Last Name" maxlength="255" class="input-text required-entry" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="wide">
<label for="billing:street1" class="required"><em>*</em>Address</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input autocomplete="on" type="text" title="Street Address" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="840 Massachusetts Avenue" class="input-text validate-english-alphanum-with-spaces required-entry" />
</div>
</li>
<li class="wide">
<label for="billing:street2">Apt, Suite, P.O.</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" title="Apt, Suite, P.O." name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street2" value="" class="input-text validate-english-alphanum-with-spaces " maxlength="12" />
</div>
</li>
<li class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em>Country</label>


</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:region_id" class="required"><em>*</em>State/Province</label>
<div class="input-box">
<select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="State/Province" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
<option value="">Please select region, state or province</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="Massachusetts" title="State/Province" class="input-text regions" style="display:none;" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:city" class="required"><em>*</em>City</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="City" name="billing[city]" value="Lexington" class="input-text validate-english-alphanum-with-spaces required-entry" id="billing:city" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:postcode" class="required"><em>*</em>Zip</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="Zip" name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" value="02420" class="input-text validate-zip-international required-entry" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em>Telephone</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="tel" maxlength="20" name="billing[telephone]" value="321456987456" title="Telephone" class="input-text validate-phone-length validate-phoneLax required-entry validate-length minimum-length-10 maximum-length-255" id="billing:telephone" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="fields" id="register-customer-password">
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:customer_password" class="required"><em>*</em>Password</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="password" name="billing[customer_password]" id="billing:customer_password" title="Password" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:confirm_password" class="required"><em>*</em>Confirm Password</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="password" name="billing[confirm_password]" title="Confirm Password" id="billing:confirm_password" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="no-display"><input type="hidden" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" /></li>
</ul>
<div class="remember-me-popup">
<div class="remember-me-popup-head">
<h3>What's this?</h3>
<a href="#" class="remember-me-popup-close" title="Close">Close</a>

</div>
<div class="remember-me-popup-body">
<p>Checking &quot;Remember Me&quot; will let you access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out</p>
<div class="remember-me-popup-close-button a-right">
<a href="#" class="remember-me-popup-close button" title="Close"><span>Close</span></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="control">
<input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1" checked="checked" title="Ship to this address" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes">Ship to this address</label></li>
<li class="control">
<input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0" title="Ship to different address" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no">Ship to different address</label>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="buttons-set" id="billing-buttons-container">
<button type="button" title="Continue" class="button" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>
<span class="please-wait" id="billing-please-wait" style="display:none;">
<img src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/rwd /opc-ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading next step..." title="Loading next step..." class="v-middle" /> Loading next step... </span>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</li>
<li id="opc-shipping" class="section allow saved">
<div class="step-title">
<span class="number">3</span>
<h2>Shipping Address</h2>
<a href="#">Edit</a>

</div>
<div id="checkout-step-shipping" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
<form action="" id="co-shipping-form">
<ul class="form-list">
<li id="shipping-new-address-form" class="scaffold-form">
<div class="fieldset">
<p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
<input type="hidden" name="shipping[address_id]" value="6427609" id="shipping:address_id" />
<ul>
<li class="fields"><div class="customer-name">
<div class="field name-firstname">
<label for="shipping:firstname" class="required"><em>*</em>First Name:</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" id="shipping:firstname" name="shipping[firstname]" value="f" title="First Name" maxlength="255" class="input-text required-entry" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false)" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="field name-lastname">
<label for="shipping:lastname" class="required"><em>*</em>Last Name:</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" id="shipping:lastname" name="shipping[lastname]" value="k" title="Last Name" maxlength="255" class="input-text required-entry" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false)" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="wide">
<label for="shipping:street1" class="required"><em>*</em>Address</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="Street Address" name="shipping[street][]" id="shipping:street1" value="840 Massachusetts Avenue" class="input-text validate-english-alphanum-with-spaces required-entry" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" />
</div>
</li>
<li class="wide">
<label for="shipping:street2">Apt, Suite, P.O.</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="Apt, Suite, P.O." name="shipping[street][]" id="shipping:street2" value="" class="input-text validate-english-alphanum-with-spaces" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" maxlength="12" />
</div>
</li>
<li class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="shipping:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em>Country</label>
<div class="input-box">

</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="shipping:region" class="required"><em>*</em>State/Province</label>
<div class="input-box">
<select id="shipping:region_id" name="shipping[region_id]" title="State/Province" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
<option value="">Please select region, state or province</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="shipping:region" name="shipping[region]" value="Massachusetts" title="State/Province" class="input-text regions" style="display:none;" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="shipping:city" class="required"><em>*</em>City</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="City" name="shipping[city]" value="Lexington" class="input-text validate-english-alphanum-with-spaces required-entry" id="shipping:city" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="shipping:postcode" class="required"><em>*</em>Zip</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" title="Zip" name="shipping[postcode]" id="shipping:postcode" value="02420" class="input-text validate-zip-international required-entry" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="fields">
<div class="field">
<label for="shipping:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em>Telephone</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="tel" maxlength="20" name="shipping[telephone]" value="321456987456" title="Telephone" class="input-text validate-phone-length validate-phoneLax required-entry validate-length minimum-length-10 maximum-length-255" id="shipping:telephone" onchange="shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);" />
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="no-display"><input type="hidden" name="shipping[save_in_address_book]" value="1" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li class="control">
<input type="checkbox" name="shipping[same_as_billing]" id="shipping:same_as_billing" value="1" checked="checked" title="Use Billing Address" onclick="shipping.setSameAsBilling(this.checked)" class="checkbox" /><label for="shipping:same_as_billing">Use Billing Address</label>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="buttons-set" id="shipping-buttons-container">
<p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="checkout.back(); return false;"><small>&laquo; </small>Back</a></p>
<button type="button" class="button" title="Continue" onclick="shipping.save()"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>
<span id="shipping-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display:none;">
<img src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend /images/opc-ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading next step..." title="Loading next step..." class="v-middle" /> Loading next step... </span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</li>
<li id="opc-shipping_method" class="section allow">
<div class="step-title">
<span class="number">4</span>
<h2>Shipping Method</h2>
<a href="#">Edit</a>

</div>
<div id="checkout-step-shipping_method" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
<form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="">
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
<!-- Content loaded dynamically -->
<h3 class="required mobile-special"><em>*</em> Delivery time is estimated in business days</h3>
<input type=hidden id="transaction_id" value='' />
<dl class="sp-methods">
<dd>
<ul>
<li class="header-sp">
<span class="select-method-frame required"><em>*</em> Select Method</span>
<label>
<span class="service">Service</span>
<span class="price-cell">Delivery Time</span>
<span class="price-cell">Cost</span>
</label>
</li>
<!--<dd>-->
<!--<ul>-->
<li>
<div class="select-method-frame">
<span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="shqusps1st_1st_class_US48_envelope" id="s_method_shqusps1st_1st_class_US48_envelope" checked="checked" /></span>
</div>
<label for="s_method_shqusps1st_1st_class_US48_envelope">
<span class="service">
<span class="method-title">Standard </span> <span class="method-extra"></span> </span>
<span class="price-cell price-cell-days">
5 - 6 </span>
<span class="price-cell">
<span class="price">$0.00</span> </span>
</label>
</li>
<!--</ul>-->
<!--</dd>-->
</ul>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
</div>
<div class="buttons-set" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
<p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="checkout.back(); return false;"><small>&laquo; </small>Back</a></p>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="shippingMethod.save()"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>
<span id="shipping-method-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display:none;">
<img src="http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/rwd /images/opc-ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading next step..." title="Loading next step..." class="v-middle" /> Loading next step... </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post HTML instead of example. So it will helpful for us  to give exact answer

Comment: Hi, i have shared my html. please look at code and suggest me.

Answer (score 5):

#### Why your attempts failed:

- your first attempt:

  ```
  WebElement button = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button[@class='button' and @type = 'button' and @onclick = 'shippingMethod.save()']")).get(3);    button.click();
  ```

  *The CSS selector is not valid* - attributes should not start with `@`, `and` is not used to join conditions in the CSS selectors.
- your second attempt:

  ```
  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@oneclick,'shippingMethod.save()']//button[contains(text(),'continue')]"))).click();
  ```

  Here the problem is in the `button[contains(text(),'continue')]` part - the *`text()` of your desired button is actually empty* because that `continue` you are looking for is on the deeper depth level, `button[contains(.//text(),'continue')]` would've worked.
- your third attempt: again, *not a valid CSS selector*

And, overall, I would not go the way of getting the `button` by an index - relying on that it is the 4th, or the last button on the page, because in this case you make your locator dependent on the buttons positions on the page - simple layout changes will break it.

#### Solution

There are multiple ways to get to the desired button, probably one of the simplest would be to check the `title` attribute to be `Continue` and for `onclick` to contain `shipping`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[title=Continue][onclick*=shipping]"))
```

Or, even easier would be to check the `id` of the parent container element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#shipping-method-buttons-container button"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a simple construct for cases like this which might be a little runtime heavy but at least finds the Element reliably.

```
static WebElement getElement(By Type, String Attr, String ExpVal){
    List<WebElement> Elems = driver.findElement(Type); //just throw down an unique as possible locator (ex. By.tagName("button"))
    for(WebElement Elem : Elems){
        if(Elem.getAttribute(Attr).contains(ExpVal) return Elem; //Attr is the unique Attribute (in your case "onclick") ExpVal is the corresponding Value.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, finally i got solution from [seleniumhq](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotInteractableException.html).

```
         System.out.print("Enabled");
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                     .xpath("//div[@id ='shipping-method-buttons-
         container']/button/span/span[text()='Continue']")));

         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id ='shipping-method-buttons-
         container']/button/span/span[text()='Continue']")).click();
```

**Reason is** "public class ElementNotInteractableException
extends InvalidElementStateException.
Thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the DOM, it is not in a state that can be interacted with."

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
You should try using `By.Xpath`, the x path will be of the child element element(button 4) will be :

```
.//button[@title = 'Continue']
```

**Option 2:**
`find_all_elements` of type button and store in a list and access the one you want.